# Wireless Interface Not Found on a MacBook 4,1 

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

I spent the last several days trying to figure this out, only finding results for the MacBook Pro 8,X model series.

**Symptoms**:

1. No wireless connectivity
2. `ifconfig` shows only eth0 (wired ethernet) interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-2/Oneiric#Wireless), although it too is posted for working for the MacBook Pro 8,2 series.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpodroid/mactel
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

Then install the linux-backports-modules-cw-3.2-oneiric-generic or, if you have the pae kernel installed, the linux-backports-modules-cw-3.2-oneiric-generic-pae package.

Edit the /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and add the line:

```
blacklist ndiswrapper
```

Create or edit the file /etc/pm/config.d/modules and make sure the wireless modules (b43 and bcma) are blacklisted:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="b43 bcma"
```

Reboot and the wireless should work.